# yet another "gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received." while lftp

Tags: handshake, lftp, gnutls

I tried setting the following:

set ftp:initial-prot ""
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ftp:ssl-auth TLS

and  am on RHEL4 trying to lftp to a 2010 Windows server but I am getting

Fatal error: gnutls_handshake: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

Can you please let me know what is that am missing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `set ftp:ssl-auth SSL` or otherwise tweak `ssl:priority` setting to match the server's capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

whitelisting/enabling the following ports solved my problem:

TCP ports: 989, 990, 991, 3000-3050, 5000-5100